# z-Index slide show using the next button

Tags: javascript, button, z-index

So I have to code a button that uses z-index to go to the next picture in the slideshow. I am having difficulty trying to get it to work and I feel as though I am doing something wrong. It has to have a count of 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "en">
<head>
<title>Lab 5, Part 1</title>
<meta charset = "utf-8"/>
<script type = "text/javascript">
function Next() {
document.getElementById('anime1').style.zIndex = 0;
document.getElementById('anime2').style.zIndex = 1;
document.getElementById('anime3').style.zIndex = 2;
}
</script>
<style type = "text/css">
.anime1 {position: absolute;
top: 150px; left: 250px; z-index: 10;}
.anime2 {position: absolute; 
top: 200px; left: 300px; z-index: 15;}
.anime3 {position: absolute; 
top: 250px; left: 350px; z-index: 20;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1 style= "text-align: center">Lab 5, Part 1</h1>
<p>
<div class="slideshow">
<img class = "anime1" id = "anime1" height = "300"
width = "450" src = "http://images5.fanpop.com/image/photos/29300000/Megurine-Luka-megurine-luka-29391390-1680-1050.jpg" 
alt = "First Image"/>
<img class = "anime2" id = "anime2" height = "300"
width = "450" src = "http://orig06.deviantart.net/a28f/f/2015/079/9/a/hinata_final_lr_by_artgerm-d8me6vb.jpg" 
alt = "Second Image"/>
<img class = "anime3" id = "anime3" height = "300"
width = "450" src = "http://images6.fanpop.com/image/photos/35700000/Hatsune-Miku-snowangel_-35736242-1600-1200.jpg" 
alt = "Third Image"/>
</p>
<input type="button" value="Next" onclick="Next();">

</body>
</html>
```

I have looked every where online to see if anything could help me but I can't find anything

Comment: Why do you think the current code you have would work? You are just strictly setting z-indexs to `0,1,2` for each `anime` element. Why would clicking it many times do anything different?

Comment: Each time the button is pressed, the next image must replace the current one. Pressing the button while the last image is displayed should return the display to the first image and start the cycle over. I have to have my count at 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/5L7jk73g/

```
var cnt = 0;

function Next() {
    if (cnt == 0) {
        document.getElementById('anime1').style.zIndex = 0;
        document.getElementById('anime2').style.zIndex = 1;
        document.getElementById('anime3').style.zIndex = 2;
        cnt++;
    } else if (cnt == 1) {
        document.getElementById('anime1').style.zIndex = 1;
        document.getElementById('anime2').style.zIndex = 2;
        document.getElementById('anime3').style.zIndex = 0;
        cnt++;
    } else {
        document.getElementById('anime1').style.zIndex = 2;
        document.getElementById('anime2').style.zIndex = 0;
        document.getElementById('anime3').style.zIndex = 1;
        cnt = cnt - 2;
    }
}
```

Comment: *Note* You can probably separate the redundant setting of `z-indexes` into it's own function.

Comment: Oh, so I was doing it wrong. I had an idea of it but didn't think about everything else. So if I wanted to do a prev button, it would be like that but instead of adding I would subtract?

Comment: @ChynnaDoll yeah, it was just an example to get you on the right track.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek I did it this way so it is very easy for the OP to understand, you seem to want to give OP a hard time for some reason?

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith its not even that hard... just do function setZIndex(element, zIndex) { document.getElementById(element).style.zIndex= zIndex; }

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith I'm not trying to give the OP a hard time, and separating redundant code would not make it harder to understand. That's like not using a for loop because you are worried the OP wouldn't understand it and instead have many similar lines of code.

Comment: I see all these great idea's however none of you posted an answer, they are just idea's at this point....

Answer (score 5):

If you're willing to take a more programmatic approach, you can use an array to hold the order and iterate it to set the z-indexes.

Using this method you can

- [`pop()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop) the item from the end of the array and [`unshift()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift) it onto the beginning, or
- [`shift()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift) the item from the beginning of the array and [`push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) it onto the end.

Which allows you to easily handle any number of elements while keeping your code [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself).

I've taken the liberty of making a back button as well as the next button, to show you how easy it is when approaching it this way. I've also generalized the class names and used different placeholder images for the demo.

```js
(function(){ // keep it safe
    var slideshow = document.querySelector('.slideshow'); // store the parent
    var controls = slideshow.querySelector('.controls');  // store the controls
    var els = slideshow.querySelectorAll('.slide');       // store the slides
    var order = Object.keys(els);                         // store the order
    var cn;                                               // make the class holder
    
    // assign a click handler to the parent
    controls.onclick = function(e) {
        // if the class is back or next, store it, otherwise stop here
        if(!(cn = (e.target.className.match(/back|next/)||[false])[0])) return;
        // if back clicked, move the last element to the beginning
        if(cn === "back") order.unshift(order.pop());
        // if next clicked, move the first element to the end
        if(cn === "next") order.push(order.shift());
        // iterate the order, set the z-index of each element sequentially
        for(var i in order) els[order[i]].style.zIndex = i;
    }
})();
```

```css
.slides { position: relative; margin-top: 5px; }
.slide  { position: absolute; }
.slide2 { top: 25px; left: 25px; }
.slide3 { top: 50px; left: 50px; }
```

```html
<div class="slideshow">
  <div class="controls">
    <button class="back">Back</button>
    <button class="next">Next</button>
  </div>
  <div class="slides">
    <img class="slide slide1" src="http://placehold.it/150x150/f9fd42/fff">
    <img class="slide slide2" src="http://placehold.it/150x150/42f9fd/fff">
    <img class="slide slide3" src="http://placehold.it/150x150/fd42f9/fff">
  </div>
</div>
```

#### Further Reading

- [Array.prototype.pop() <sup><sub>(MDN)</sub></sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop)
- [Array.prototype.unshift() <sup><sub>(MDN)</sub></sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift)
- [Array.prototype.shift() <sup><sub>(MDN)</sub></sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift)
- [Array.prototype.push() <sup><sub>(MDN)</sub></sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)
- [Don't Repeat Yourself <sup><sub>(Wikipedia)</sub></sup>](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself)